# Transaction, multiple databases, different servers: MSDTC or any other option

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql, msdtc

I am working on a client-server application and using LINQ to SQL to perform databases operations, 1 databases is on server and multiple clients will connect to it and there will be sync of databases records as well, Trying to manage a transaction with multiple datacontext and multiple databases but getting error on MSDTC service that it is not configured, before I go to configure I want to ask Is the MSDTC the only option? It will not be available in shared hosting then what type of hosting i should be looking for?

Any other thing I need to check before I go to MSDTC configuration? Is this service required only on server or must be configured on each client machine?

Comment: LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: Be sure to test it with the hosting provider first because they might well not support it. Consider not using multiple databases. Or, consider using the same connection with multiple databases.

Comment: I am open to consider LINQ to SQL or Entity framework, which 1 is close to the requirement?

Comment: I have spoken to hosting provider and they said MSDTC will not b available on shared hosting. If it is a client server application, how can I use same database and how same connection string will wotk on multiple databases?